# Pointer to Array in function call in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

i'm a bit confused about using pointers.

I want to hand over the array to the pointer and then get the result of the function from the pointer.
The function just returns the minimum of an array.

```
int *minimum(int (*A)[5]){
    int min = 0;
    int A_result[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if ((*A)[i]< (*A)[min])
            min = i;
     }

    A_result[0] = (*A)[min];

    return A_result;  //line 39
}


int main(void) {

    int A[5] = {5, 7, 3, 6, 4};
    int (*array_ptr)[5] = minimum(&A);  //line 45

    printf("%d ", *array_ptr);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

by now i get the following errors:

line 45: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

line 39: 
function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

Comment: Why do you want to return a pointer to `int` from `second_lowest()` when your function only is supposed to find one `int` (`int min`) ?

Comment: What is the reason to pass a pointer to `A` to your function? Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first argument, so you could have `second_lowest(int *A)` and pass plain `A` (which will then decay to `&A[0]`). Dealing with pointers to arrays complicates it a lot, especially since you return-type is not matching what `array_ptr` is and what you actually return (a pointer to a *local* variable which will cease to exist once you return). All in all there's so many things wrong with this little piece of code, I think you should go back and start over with "hello world".

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass pointer to array to the function second_lowest. Also, no point in returning a pointer from the function second_lowest. I modified your code :

```
int second_lowest(int *A) {
    int min = 0;
    int A_result;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (A[i] < A[min])
            min = i;
    }

    A_result = A[min];

    return A_result;  //line 39
}

int main(void) {

    int A[5] = { 5, 7, 3, 6, 4 };
    int res = second_lowest(A);  //line 45

    printf("%d ", res);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Irene, your basics regarding C are quite weak. It is better you study the basics properly. Also, if the above answer which is absolutely correct, does not meet your requirement, then please state the exact requirements of your question

Comment: Irene, I think then they would be requiring you to return pointer to the second min. You could do something like int* A_result; .... A_result = (*A) + min; in your original code.

Comment: Juhuuu, did it by my own! Thank you!